# Intellij (ultimate) log4j issues when trying to install (ubuntu)

Tags: intellij-idea, log4j

I've been trying to get my student ultimate Intellij edition to install on my fresh Ubuntu installation for past 2 days. After reading other threads/apache info apparently it can't find my configuration file. I've tried adding a classpath and the files manually. Heres the error :

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>       log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig     for more
>   info.
>           [    207]   WARN -     #com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil - Cannot register     font: jar:file:/home/overlord/Downloads/idea-IU-
>   143.1821.5/lib/resources.jar!/fonts/Inconsolata.ttf 
>       java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.

And then a bunch of null pointer references since it can't load the font since it cant find the customization file(I believe is the issue)

grep -R log4j gave me:

> log4j.properties:log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
>       log4j.properties:log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>       log4j.properties:log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>       log4j.properties:log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
>       log4j.properties:log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
>       idea.sh:CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$IDE_HOME/lib/log4j.jar"
>       log.xml:
>       log.xml:
>       log.xml:  
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:  
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:  
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:  
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:  
>       log.xml:    
>       log.xml:

So I added IDE_HOME classpath to my intellij folder thinking it couldn't find the xml or properties file. Then I realized I didn't see any xml or property files so I added log4j.properties to both the intellij folder and the bin. The default from apache was :

> # Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
>       log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, # A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
>           log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>
> ```
> # A1 uses PatternLayout.
> log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
>
> # Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
> log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
> ```

Still no luck now and I'm not sure what else I can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still in trouble or for future reference, you've to install libxft2

apt-get install libxft2

I also need these packages:

apt-get install libxtst6 libxrender1 libxi6